# How to get second object out from linq in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a question. i want to get second object out from linq in C#

```
int userSkillID = Convert.ToInt32(linq1.tbl_ProjectImplementationProcesses
   .Where(c => c.ProjectID == Convert.ToInt32(cmb_projectName.SelectedValue))
   .Select(c => c.UserSkillsID).First());
```

first -->deletion

Replaced --?

Comment: Delete and then repeat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `Skip()`:

```
.Select(c => c.UserSkillsID).Skip(1).First()
```

Comment: Without ordering it hasn't meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Skip and Take in a combination:

```
int userSkillID = Convert.ToInt32(linq1.tbl_ProjectImplementationProcesses
   .Where(c => c.ProjectID == Convert.ToInt32(cmb_projectName.SelectedValue))
   .Select(c => c.UserSkillsID).Skip(1).Take(1);
```

Source: [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)